# Sending data to the printer does not work - zebra gt430x

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, tampermonkey, zebra-printers

I have a problem with the code. It tries to send an ASIN code to the printer in the form of a ZPL code, but the printer does not respond after sending data.

The code looks like this:

```
$('.fcrp-tooltip').append('<a class="fcrp-tix ">Print</a>');

$('.fcrp-tix').click(function print(){
    var zpl = "^XA^BY2,2,70^FO40,80^BC^'+itemAsin+'^FS^XZ";
    var url = "http://localhost:5965";
    var method = "POST";
    var async = true;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onload = function () {
    var status = request.status;
    var data = request.responseText;
    output.innerHTML = "Status: " + status + "<br>" + data;
    }

    request.open(method, url, async);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", zpl.length);


    request.send(zpl);
    });
```

Comment: Please show the final content of the zpl string in your question, too.

Comment: I suspect you need additional ZPL commands to print, at least a ``^PQ`` command. Please see to the ZPL programming guide for details. You can find a link in the zebra-printers tag description!

Comment: @DelphiCoder I want the printer to finally print the product barcode along with its name. "itemAsin" is a product code that, after clicking on it and then clicking on <a> Print</a>, would send this code to the printer and print it

Comment: That's ok, but as I said, your barcode command alone is not enough